# why not display correctly bootstrap praragraph in laravel

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am using this bootstrap blade view in Laravel. But my `view file` did not display correctly. That means my `@extends('layouts.app')` override `<div class="container">`

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
                <h5>Wealth Lanka Management (Private) Ltd (Wealth Lanka or WLM) is a specialized investment banking and financial consultancy firm engaged in feasibility studies , project advisory services, investment banking, capital market and corporate advisory services as well as consultancy services.The main promoters, Messrs Mangala Boyagoda and Asoka Sirimane possess over three decades of local and international expertise in financial and business management, banking and financial services.</h5>                                                                      
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>                
@endsection
```

How can I fix this?

**updated**
app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="{{asset('favicon.ico')}}">

    <title>Wealth Lanka</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="{{asset('css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="{{asset('js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{{asset('css/carousel.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
 <body>
     <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="{{asset('/imgs/logo.png')}}"></a>
                  {{--  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WEALTH LANKA MANAGEMENT</a>--}}
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            {{-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav">--}}
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/about') }}">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Boad of Ditectors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Senior Team</a></li>
                    {{-- <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>--}}
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#about">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>
  </div>
      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    @yield('content')
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
    <script src="{{asset('js/vendor/holder.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="{{asset('js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js')}}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you mean 'override'? is `<div class="container">` not in your HTML anymore once the page is loaded?

Comment: Also add the content of your layouts.app please

Comment: I mean My <div class="container"> contents are sink in (layouts.app).

Comment: see updated answer